# Как перебрать вложенные FormGroup?

Tags: typescript, angular

У меня есть FormGroup созданная с помощью FormBuilder:

```
this.LeadControl = this.fb.group({
      leadId: Guid.create().toString(),
      leadStatus: ['', Validators.required],
      firmName: ['', Validators.required],
      contactPhones: this.fb.array([ ['', Validators.required] ]),
      contactName: '',
      position: '',
      contactEmail: ['', Validators.email],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      lprsName: '',
      comments: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          description: '',
          createdDate: new Date
        })
      ]),
      tasks: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          status: 'started',
          action: ['', Validators.required],
          description: ['', Validators.required],
          createdDate: new Date,
          deadLineDate: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      ]),
      link2gis: '',
      createdDate: new Date
    });
```

Мне необходимо перебрать все элементы FormGroup и удалить пустые FormControl

```
for(let x in this.LeadControl) {
      if (x === '' || x === null) {
        this.LeadControl.removeControl(x);
      }
}
```

Но мой основной FormGroup - 'LeadControl' имеет вложенные FormGroup, а конкретнее во вложенных FG я хочу проверить элемент description.
Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: идите в цикле по ключам объекта `controls`, проверьте что контрол инстанс класса `FormArray`, если да - заходите внутрь и идите по массиву `controls`

Comment: Я где то это видел, но у меня пример из интернета выдавал ошибку. Вы сможете привести собственный пример. Если вам будет не сложно?

Comment: Я нашел пример в интернете. Спасибо! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls